# How should I support an opening in a brick wall for an air conditioner?

Tags: structural, masonry

I’m going to install a [Pelonis air conditioning unit](https://www.pelonis.com/us/air-conditioners/through-the-wall-ac) through a brick wall. I was wondering what type of structural support I’ll need before I go and knock out a hole.

The game plan is to drill pilot holes on the inside (since I already have the plaster wall cutout done) and on the inside of each corner of the rectangle. Then I’ll be able to go outside and use a grinder or a masonry saw to cut out the outside brick wall.

I think there’s some type of metal plate I have to put above the opening in order to support the bricks above from caving in. I don’t know if this is installed before hand or not ( I tuckpointed all of the joints 2 years ago so it should be structurally sound).

There're actually two brick walls back to back on this building, the building is quite old (1920 roughly) so I have to take out two rectangles instead of just one.

Comment: Not a plate, but an angle called a "lintel". A plate wouldn't have the stiffness required. Have you looked into this at all? It's a very old practice and information abounds on it.

Comment: Or this? [How can I cut through brick to add a window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13459/how-can-i-cut-through-brick-to-add-a-window)

Comment: Or this? [Can I cut a hole in the brick to install a through the wall air conditioner in a basement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71546/can-i-cut-a-hole-in-the-brick-to-install-a-through-the-wall-air-conditioner-in-a)

Comment: Seems like a great deal of work  and expense to install an outdated A/C (9.3 EER - embarrassing) when an up-to-current tech A/C would merely involve one small hole in the wall for the minisplit lineset.